# Find the length of segment $AJ$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Let $H$ be the orthocentre of an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and $J$ be the orthocentre of the triangle $HBC$. $AB=6\sqrt3$.
>    Find the length of $AJ$.

My friend thinks that $A$ and $J$ will align themselves, making the length of the segment $AJ$ will $0$. I don't quite get him and his theory of how they can coincide. Is he right? If no, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But $A\equiv J$, which says that $AJ=0$.

Indeed, $AH\perp BC$, $AC\perp BH$ and $AB\perp CH$,

which says that $A$ is an ortocenter of $\Delta BHC$, which unique for all triangle.

Comment: can you post a link for the diagram? I am having difficulty understanding how $A\equiv J$

Comment: @LinuxGeek I can not draw in the net. But $A$ is an orthocenter by definition. Let $M$ be a midpoint of $AB$ and $K$ be a mid point of $AC$. Hence, $CK$ and $BM$ are altitudes of $\Delta BHC$ and $CK\cap BM=\{A\}$.